# Python 3 https connection via sockets

Tags: python, sockets, web, python-3.x

I need to use https connection via sockets(to use socks proxy), I'm trying to use ssl but get an error:

```
>>> import socket
>>> import ssl
>>> s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
>>> s.connect(("www.google.com.ua",443))
>>> ss=ssl.wrap_socket(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    ss=ssl.wrap_socket(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/ssl.py", line 521, in wrap_socket
    ciphers=ciphers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/ssl.py", line 276, in __init__
    raise x
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/ssl.py", line 272, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/ssl.py", line 451, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [Errno 8] _ssl.c:392: EOF occurred in violation of protocol
```

How can I make it right? Thnx in advance.

Comment: Might not be the solution, but the SSL (HTTPS) port is 443, not 80.

Comment: Snx, but error still occurs.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't reproduce the error using python 3.2.3.  I don't know much about pyshell, but could pyshell be causing to the problem?

Comment: @Brionius, sorry, i don't understand, this code works on your computer? i test on the same version of python.

Comment: Yes - it runs without an error - sorry!

Comment: @Brionius, hm... it's really strange... any way if i start tls first, and then connecting to server all works.